# CodeIgniter - Form Validation callback issues

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im wondering if someone can clear things up for me.

In my codeigniter form validation rules i have a callback called email_exists, its set as follows

```
->set_rules( 'login', 'Email Address', 'trim|valid_email|required|xss_clean|callback__email_exists' )
```

In the same controller i have the function it calls as follows

```
function _email_exists()
{
    // Code here
}
```

This works perfectly, and i cant access the method from the URL because of the _ before the method name ... So its working perfect.

I have looked at the CI documentation and it says for callbacks to use a private method ... but everytime i put 'private' before the method name, it doesnt work at all.

Is it ok to just leave it as it is.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method cannot be private as the validation class is not able to access the callback method.

[The documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) also shows that the callback method should be declared as public.

You should leave it as it is.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh ... It just occured to me that the validation is a seperate class hahahaha ... Ok, thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to leave it as it is, because CodeIgniters _ prefix will prevent public access to the method (which means its not possible to access the function by URL as you mentioned).

The [manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#private) might be a bit confusing on this part, as they define functions prefixed by _ as private (what they really mean is hidden from public access). However a function might still be declared public (like you have in your code) but still be hidden from public access.